# htaccess redirect to https but exclude 1 php file with variable

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

i've a htaccess that redirect all pages into https, but how to make ads.php file to exclude from this?

i've try code like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(/ads.php.*)\s [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but still redirecting into https.

so basicly i need to redirect all  hxxp://sub.domain.com -> https://sub.domain.com,
but for hxxp://sub.domain.com/ads.php?var=xxxxx aren't getting redirected into https.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `RewriteCond` in your rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ads\.php$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

to exclude ads.php

Comment: still using https, :(